# Сколько времени прошло

Tags: timestamp, unixtimestamp, php, javascript

У меня есть 2 даты в любом формате (допустим в Timestamp)
Мне нужно узнать сколько времени прошло от одного времени до другого. 
Конечно я могу просто вычесть одну дату из другой, и получить время в секундах.
Но мне необходимо узнать сколько времени прошло в ДНЯХ, МЕСЯЦАХ и ГОДАХ, учитывая високосные года и что в разных месяцах разное кол-во дней.

То есть, если событие произошло 1 октября этого года (вторая дата пусть будет сегодня), то прошло ноль дней, один месяц и ноль лет. Если событие произошло 15 октября, то прошло 17 дней, ноль месяцев и ноль лет.

Все это нужно реализовать с помощью PHP или Java Script. Заранее благодарен =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче говоря, ребята, спасибо за кучу ссылок. [[@thunder](/users/9040/thunder)](/users/9040/thunder) мне твоя ссылка очень помогла. 
Но, как бы там ни было, ответ я напишу сам

```
<?php
   $time = '2012-06-12 16:56';
   $datetime1 = date_create($time);
   $datetime2 = date_create('now',new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
   $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
   $interval->format('%y years %M months %D days');
?>
```

Если что-то не верно, комментируйте

Answer (score 2):

Ну например:

```
$day = floor( ($next - $past) / 86400 );
print "Между данными датами прошло <b>". $day ."</b> дней";
```

Comment: Месяцев и лет =\

Comment: как раз хотел добавить, можно почитать про полезный класс в пхп [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)  
там как раз возвращается массив с днем/месяцем/годом/часом/минутой/секундой =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$t1=time();
// что-то делаем, делаем, делаем, делаем
$t2=time();
$times=$t2-$t1;

echo "Time running script ".$times. "seconds";
```

ну и в таком духе, ну а потом преобразовать его в нормальный вид

ну и вот [тут](http://n-wp.ru/12579) есть готовое решение

Comment: не открывается ссыль

Comment: Почти так, но есть одно "НО", этот скрипт дает относительную дату, то есть "событие произошло примерно 4 месяца назад", а дни не считаются

Comment: почитайте про date_diff

Comment: НУ то что не открывается, значит у человека отстойный хостинг и не выдерживает хешкодэффекта :)

Comment: Ссыль открывается, но почему-то долго

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date_diff(new DateTime(), new DateTime('2015-10-09 00:00:01'))->days;
```