# Сколько прошло времени?

Tags: php, дата

Доброе утро ХэшКод.

Как сделать отсчет того, сколько времени прошло после (например, добавления новости), я делал так

```
$date = date("G:i:s", time() - $res["date"])
echo $date;
```

Но беда в том, что даже если добавит в базу текущее время, отсчет начинается, и не с 0 часов 0 минут и 0 секунд, а сразу как будто я отправил сообщение 2 часа назад, т.е отсчет идёт не от нуля, а от 2-х.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = date("G:i:s", time() - $res["date"])
echo $date;
```

Я обычно ставлю **H** а не **G**

```
G Часы в 24-часовом формате без ведущего нуля
H Часы в 24-часовом формате с ведущим нулём

time() Возвращает количество секунд
```

$res["date"] откуда берется?

**Но скорее вопрос именно в Букве при выводе.**

**//UPD**
Ну вот чтобы огород не городить уже отвечал на вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159672#159673)

Comment: Из Базы, там тоже секунлы.

Comment: Мне нужен примерно такой результат: 0:01:56, а получается 2:01:56

Comment: Обновил ответ т.к. подобный вопрос уже был задан.

Comment: У меня там ошибкa:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_diff() in Z:\home\koni.ru\www\add.php on line 15

Comment: Где ты там в коде по ссылке в моем ответе нашел про** date_diff() **???

Я поражаюсь, даже если дать ссылку на решение вопроса, можно наступить на грабли, еще и не раз!