# Сколько времени прошло

Tags: python, diff, время

Это не является копией [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159672/php-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE) вопроса, но тот же самый функционал должен быть реализован на python... У меня есть готовый шаблон плазмоида. Я "[спер](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=143166)" исходники одного таймера и поменял местами настоящее время и сохраненное. Получил почти ожидаемый результат -- разницу между настоящим временем и записанным. Только меня не устраивает формат вывода. Выводит `400 days, 4:40:00`, а мне нужно `1 years 01 months 05 days, 4:40:00`

Вот те заветные строчки:

```
    n = datetime.now()
    timeDiff = n - self.end
    painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter, str(timeDiff).split(".")[0])
```

Все как бы понятно, только как изменить формат вывода. Прошу вас, великие python кодеры, напишите, пожалуйста, мне эти несколько жалких строчек решения этой задачи. Я с этим языком не знаком абсолютно и не хочу изучать его ради этой, простой для вас задачки. Заранее очень благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудность заключается в точном подсчете числа лет, длина года меняется. Можно использовать, например, модуль dateutil:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> end = dt.datetime(2001,1,1)
>>> n = dt.datetime.now()
>>> relativedelta(n, end)
relativedelta(years=+12, months=+6, days=+21, hours=+16, minutes=+25, seconds=+50, microseconds=+812805)
```

А что касается вопроса ниже, можно использовать `zfill`, если очень охота форматировать самому: `str(5).zfill(2)` даст `'05'`, а `str(12).zfill(2)` даст `'12'`. В приведенном примере это можно использовать так:

```
str(relativedelta(n,end).months).zfill(2)
```

Хотя я бы сохранил результат relativedelta(n, end) в отдельную переменную, и уже из нее дергал бы данные для форматирования, ибо незачем каждый раз вычислять их.

Comment: Что-то не особо что-то получается. Можете, пожалуйста показать, как создать строковую переменную, чтобы вывести ее на экран?

Comment: Можно сказать, я почти понял. Но как по отдельности достать год, месяц, день, час, минуты и секунды, чтобы нормально отформатировать?

Comment: Очень просто: relativedelta(n, end).years для лет, остальное аналогично.

Comment: А что касается вопроса ниже, можно использовать zfill, если очень охота форматировать самому: str(5).zfill(2) даст '05', а str(12).zfill(2) даст '12'.
В приведенном примере это можно использовать так: str(relativedelta(n,end).months).zfill(2)
Хотя я бы сохранил результат relativedelta(n, end) в отдельную переменную, и уже из нее дергал бы данные для форматирования, ибо незачем каждый раз вычислять их.

Comment: @viem77 можешь сделать это полноценным ответом на вопрос, чтобы я смог закрыть вопрос, а ты получить очки)

Comment: @vital_viza, готово :)

Answer (score 0):

Хочу представить свой костыль. Люди-профессионалы, может есть выход проще и я зря корячился?
[image: Скриншот]

```
    n = datetime.now()
    timeDiff = datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0) + relativedelta(n, self.end)
    year = timeDiff.year - 2011
    if year < 10:
     year = '0'+str(year)

    month = timeDiff.month - 1
    if month < 10:
     month = '0'+str(month)

    day = timeDiff.day - 1
    if day < 10:
     day = '0'+str(day)

    hour = timeDiff.hour
    if hour < 10:
     hour = '0'+str(hour)

    minute = timeDiff.minute
    if minute < 10:
     minute = '0'+str(minute)

    second = timeDiff.second
    if second < 10:
     second = '0'+str(second)

    stri = str(year)+'.'+str(month)+'.'+str(day)+'\n'+str(hour)+':'+str(minute)+':'+str(second)
    painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter, stri)
```

Работает, как нужно, но знаю, что есть выход проще

Answer (score 0):

Вот описание из стандартного питоновского мана: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Проблема в том, что я пробовал некоторые чтуки. Но у меня ничего не получалось

Comment: так а в чем конкретно была проблема?

Comment: в криворукости и незнании языка

Comment: дык может начать изучать язык? например, по моей ссылке есть достаточно информации, чтобы была возможность на нём писать

Comment: Мне это не в чему. Мне он пригодился только для виджета. А если будет необходимость, буду изучать

Comment: ну готов поспорить, что и пэхапэ есть метода для формата дат в строки, так что это не момент знания/незнания какогоя-то языка